# how do you authenticate to bitbucket api without password in python script using request.post?

Tags: python, api, bitbucket

how do you authenticate to bitbucket api without password in python script using request.post?

I am currently using this method below, `('username', 'mypwd')` but I want an alternative way,

```
r = requests.post(url, auth=('username', 'mypwd'), headers=headers, data=json.dumps(my_data), timeout=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in this [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/command-line-rest/) of the Bitbucket REST API, it accepts basic auth, which is the one you're using, OAuth and Session Authentication. All of them can be handled by requests module.

As long as I understood your question, you don't want your password to be in the code, so basic auth and session authentication are discarded, in the first moment (we will see alternatives below). OAuth seems like the only way to go but you will need to send in every post or get the authentication with information such as App Keys and Token Secrets.

Another good way to go is to store the password in another file, and by using the `os` module and the function os.environ['VariableName'] you can extract it to a local variable on code and pass it to the requests function.

Last but not least, you can use the `getpass` module to call the functions `getpass` and `getuser` which will prompt you for both, your password and username, and save them into variables.

Note: By creating a `session` object of the requests module, you will only have to "login" once, after that no other post/get will need the auth.